# Rodents fighting, now one losing weight

Tags: health, rodents

Had Ronnie and Reggie for 2.5 years. I guess they were 5/ 6 months when I got them. Last two in a pet shop. Got told the whole yes we do this and that, well they would do anything to sell.

Anyway, my boys are my fur babys, love them with all my heart. But I went away (probably explains next part), told my son to open cage, give them their fruit (my fur babys are allowed to run round my house). Why have pets if no freedom.

Anyway they have had squabbles in the past like any brother or sister, all been good but they had apparently a massive fight. Since then my Reggie (more dominant) is losing weight and looking fragile. Still gives me kisses and sleeps with his brother. My Ronnie just looks massive, so clearly Reggie has lost weight!  Reggie always been more dominant and the biggest.

From past experiences (Sly and Arnie) when taken to vets they just wanna put them down. I can't go through that again, so any suggestions? Reggie looking old and fragile just wanna make him comfy than have some vet say put him down. Please anyone help!

Comment: Sammi, I have edited your question to make it more suitable for this site. Part of this involved removing the expletive and emojis, as well as taking out some extraneous detail. Please could you clarify what species your pets are? Rats? Also can you elaborate on what question you would like answered. Please use the [edit] button below your post to make it more clear. As the questions stands, I fear you will not get any useful answer other than take them to a vet.

Comment: A quick search shows that the average lifespan of a rat is 2 years. Your pet may simply show signs of old age or he might be in pain (which might lead to fights) or at a worst case have cancer (which often leads to weight loss). The only person who could help you is a vet. Get your boys examined and if the vet tells you to put them down, you simply say "no". But keep in mind not to let them suffer if it really is something bad. They should have a happy life, not one filled with pain every day.